# Throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unable to locate factory with name

Tags: php, laravel-artisan, seed, factories

I am trying to run the command:  `php artisan db:seed` in the terminal.
I keep getting this error when trying to populate the table:

> Exception trace:
>   1   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::getRawAttributes([])
>         /srv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:305
>   2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::Illuminate\Database\Eloquent{closure}()
>         /srv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php:116

Comment: grammar, formatting

Comment: You may need to add the code or  the database that this error is referring to for volunteers to be of help, unless this is a rare error that is code-independent. If the latter is the case, then a Google search for the error message may hep. I am not familiar with this situation, so cannot be of additional assistance. Just giving a heads up from the review queue.